# is this main relay faulty, what should I do now?

Tags: electronics, relay

Civic coupe vti 1999 @ 163k miles.

Cars not starting and have just inspected the main relay and can see one of the points seems to have worn to the point you can see blue underneath it.  Will this make it faulty?

[image: main fuel relay]

No experience soldering/do I take it to any electronics shop in the U.K. to get it soldered?  Should I get one from a breakers and is there a way I look at the board and tell if it will
Last or is this not possible and can any used one with a nice board go bad in a short time and so it’s better to buy a new one?

Broke at the moment don’t want to buy new but regret buying a used ignition switch
Recently opened it up to find dirt was worse than the one I took out.  At least with the relay I should be able to request a pic of the circuit board.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It looks perfectly OK to me. That looks like a splash of blue paint that came from somewhere. Soldered joints don't "wear".  Whether the contacts inside the actual relays are worn or burned is a different question,  but troubleshooting by picking random things to worry about isn't a very effective method (as you seem to be finding out the hard way!)

Comment: Visit a scrappy and get another.

Comment: @Solar Mike would you agree with aleph though that it looks fine so may not need replacing? initially I thought the blue was from underneath the metal but I’ve just had a closer look and have to agree it looks like a see through the substance sitting on top. Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to tell if it needs replacing from your picture. For all we know it might be in perfect "as new" condition, or somebody might have attacked the actual relays (on the other side of the board) with a blowtorch and a sledge hammer.

Comment: Why ask when you can test the relay using a 9v battery and a multimeter?